# resize shadowbox with HTML content

Tags: jquery, html, shadowbox

I'm using a jquery shadowbox library, wich allows you to show HTML content in a lightbox/shadowbox. (www.shadowbox-js.com)

My question is: is there any way to dynamically resize the shadowbox when it's already open (the content becomes bigger).

You can set the start dimensions, but it seems pretty hard to change the dimensions later on

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There's a shadowbox function here: 
setDimensions(height, width, maxHeight, maxWidth, topBottom, leftRight, padding, preserveAspect)

If you could trigger this function when the content changes in the shadowbox you could get the size of the content and change the dimensions yourself.

I hope that helps. Without more details I can't give you a more specific answer.